# Pandas dataframe to dictionary where values are lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns:

```
key | value
"a" | 1
"a" | 2
"b" | 4
```

which I would like to map to a dictionary that would look like:

```
my_dict["a"] = [1,2]
my_dict["b"] = [4]
```

My current implementation is

```
for k in df["keys"].unique():
    vals = df[df["keys"] == k]["value"]
    my_dict[k] = vals
```

But this implementation takes a long time on my dataframe that has ~400k rows. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `my_dict = {k:v['value'] for k,v in df.groupby('keys')}`

Comment: `df.groupby('key')['value'].agg(list).to_dict()`

Comment: @QuangHoang That's using a dictionary comprehension, I don't think that will be significantly faster than the current implementation since python is in charge of creating the dictionary instead of pandas making it with a c extension. It might be delegated to faster python C code with a dict comprehension, but I don't think that will speed it up as much as OP is looking for

Comment: @Samathingamajig you might want to provide an answer with your suggestion, a list comprehension is likely the fastest with pure python/pandas.

Comment: @Samathingamajig that will be **significantly faster** than the current implementation, because the current one slices the data every iteration.

Comment: @mozway I mentioned an answer in my comment, to look for a pandas method for quicker conversion to a dictionary

Comment: do you want a list or a series as values in your dict? you have both answers in comments 
However , your code doesnt match the expected output

Comment: @Samathingamajig OP's solution on 1M rows input 3.7s, a dict comprehension: 200ms.

Comment: @QuangHoang can be simplified as `dict(list(df.groupby('key')['value']))`